# Map dispatch functions to array for Promise.all

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, promise, es6-promise

I have the following chunk of code, more or less:

```js
let images = [{ ... }, { ... }, { ... }, ...];

Promise.all([
  dispatch(uploadImage(images[0]),
  dispatch(uploadImage(images[1]),
  ...
]).then(() => dispatch(success());
```

Now obviously I can't hardcode this, so I would like to map the array I pass to Promise.all. What would be the easiest way to do this? I tried arrow functions, returning anonymous functions, but I just can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) that will return an array of promises.

`Promise.all(images.map((image) => dispatch(uploadImage(image))));`

**Update To Comment**

```js
const uploadImage = async() => {
  console.log("uploadImage");

  return Promise.resolve();
};

const dispatch = async() => {
  console.log("dispatch");

  return Promise.resolve();
};

const images = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];

const imagesPromises = images.map((image) => {
  return () => dispatch(uploadImage(image));
});

Promise.all(imagesPromises.map((promise) => promise())); // Promises wont execute till this line.
```

Comment: I was unsure if that executes the dispatch functions instead of adding them to an array, but didn't know how to check.

Comment: @TemporaryName, if you want to achieve that outcome, you can first create an array of functions that return the promises, then when you are ready to execute you can map over again & return & execute each promise, I've added the code snippet.

Comment: Your name `imagesPromises` is a bit misleading, the variable doesn't contain a list of promises, but instead a list of functions returning promises

Comment: @Ferrybig yes you are correct, it definitely is misleading. My bad! Any ideas on what to suggest?

Comment: @DanStarns `imageDispatchArray`